# Script with input date, output day

Tags: bash, date

I want to write a bash script that reads a keyboard input (date dd:mm:yy), stores it in a variable then echoes back the Day it corresponds to, ie

Input : 03/08/2015

Output : Wednesday

I'm having some problems with formatting this, any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Wednesday?? Also, is this a homework?

Comment: [3rd of august is Monday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/August_3)

Comment: You're having trouble formatting _what_? What do you have so far?

Comment: #!/bin/bash

echo "Enter date in string form"   #ex 22042005
read dat4

#date -jf "%Y%m%d%H%M%S" $dat4 "+date \"%A,%_d %B %Y %H:%M:%S\""

Comment: oops, this is better :

Comment: #!/bin/bash


echo "Enter date in string form"   #ex 22042005

read dat4


#date -jf "%Y%m%d%H%M%S" $dat4 "+date \"%A,%_d %B %Y %H:%M:%S\""

Comment: And yes, its for homework, i m really new to this :/

Comment: #!/bin/bash


    echo "Enter date in string form"   #ex 22042005


    read dat4


    #date -jf "%Y%m%d%H%M%S" $dat4 "+date \"%A,%_d %B %Y %H:%M:%S\""

Comment: #!/bin/bash<br/>  
    echo "Enter date in string form"   #ex 22042005<br/>   
    read dat4<br/>
    #date -jf "%Y%m%d%H%M%S" $dat4 "+date \"%A,%_d %B %Y %H:%M:%S\""<br/>

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include more details. It is easy to miss and hard to read in the comments. See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for help on formatting your posts.

Answer (score 3):

`date` accepts input with its `-d` flag, and prints it. However, input formatted like yours is treated like MM/DD/YYYY. But this shouldn't be too hard.

First, let's get input to variable:

```
read INPUT
```

Now, we need to change input from DD/MM/YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY. You can do that with sed and awk(you can also do that with `awk`:

```
INPUT=`echo $INPUT | awk -F '/' '{t=$1;$1=$2;$2=t;gsub(" ", "/");print;}'`
```

Now that INPUT is in proper format, feed it to `date` and make it only print the day:

```
date -d $INPUT +%A
```

Put it all together:

```
#!/bin/bash
read INPUT
INPUT=`echo $INPUT | awk -F '/' '{t=$1;$1=$2;$2=t;gsub(" ", "/");print;}'`
date -d $INPUT +%A
```

Comment: Awk part isn't necessary, really

Comment: Run `$ date --date='03/08/15' +%A`                           and `$ date --date='03/08/15' +%A`

Comment: @Serg two same commands? Anyway, the command you gave gives wrong output

Comment: @MathewRock  Ah, I missed that OP needed European style input (day-month-year). OK, then it's correct. +1

Answer (score 3):

Perl has some nice built-in datetime modules:

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -E '
     print "Input date (dd/mm/YYYY): ";
     chomp( $date = <> );
     $datetime = Time::Piece->strptime($date, "%d/%m/%Y");
     say $datetime->strftime("%e %B is a %A");
'
Input date (dd/mm/YYYY): 3/8/2015
 3 August is a Monday
```